# Typescript get valid combination of union types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Say I have union types like:

```
NumberOfChildren = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3+"
EldestAge = "-1" | "0-3" | "3-10" | "11-17" | "18+" // -1 for null
NextEldestAge = "-1" | "0-3" | "3-10" | "11-17" | "18+" // -1 for null
```

If I do `${NumberOfChildren}_${EldestAge}_${NextEldestAge}`

I will get invalid combinations like:

```
0_0-3_-1 // Can't have an Eldest age with no children
2_3-10_18+ // Next Eldest can't be older than eldest
```

I've tried doing conditional types like:

```
type combos<count extends string, age1 extends string, age2 extends string> =
| ([count, age1, age2] extends ["0", "-1", "-1"] ? "0_-1_-1" : "0_-1_-1")
| ([1, age1, -1] extends ["1", age1, "-1"] ? "1_${age1}_-1" : "0_-1_-1")
.... more combos
```

But the only thing that comes out is "0_-1_-1".

What's the right way to do this?  End goal is a union type with all valid combinations of the types joined with a _

EDIT: Based on vera's comment this is a solution:

```
type NumberOfChildren = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3+"
type AgeGroups = ["-1", "0-3", "3-10", "11-17", "18+"] // -1 for null

type Builder<Age extends string, AgeGroup extends string[], Previous extends string[] = []> =
    AgeGroup extends [infer Head extends string, ...infer Tail extends string[]]
        ? `${Age}_${Head}_${Exclude<Head | Previous[number], "-1">}` | Builder<Age, Tail, [...Previous, Head]>
        : never;


type ZeroChildren = `0_-1_-1`;
type OneChild = `1_${AgeGroups[number]}_-1`;
type TwoChildren = Builder<"2", AgeGroups>
type ThreeOrMoreChildren = Builder<"3", AgeGroups>;

type Test = TwoChildren;
//   ^?

type ValidCombos = ZeroChildren | OneChild | TwoChildren | ThreeOrMoreChildren;
//   ^?
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG2Vvm) work for you?

Comment: Wow that's really cool.  It's very close to correct but since you hard coded 2 the ThreeOrMore type is a copy of Two.  

I'm still digesting your code but looking at this:


TwoChildren<A extends string[] = AgeGroups, Previous extends string[] = []>


Can you replace that with TwoChildre<A, Previous....> and then call TwoChildren<AgeGroups>?

Comment: You can still use `TwoChildren<AgeGroups>` or `TwoChildren<["1", "2", "3", "whatever"]>`. It's just that by *default* it will use `AgeGroups`.

Comment: Awesome.  I was able to get it working from your solution.  If you want to post an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tuple to describe our age groups would make the implementation a little easier:

```
type AgeGroups = ["-1", "0-3", "3-10", "11-17", "18+"];
```

Let's handle all the different cases separately: 0 children, 1 child, 2 children, and 3 or more. While you could write some complex type to do it all, I think that covering them separately is easier to read and maintain.

For zero children, there is only one case which we can hardcode:

```
type ZeroChildren = `0_-1_-1`;
```

Next is one child, which is also pretty simple:

```
// exclude -1 as first child
type OneChild = `1_${Exclude<AgeGroups[number], "-1">}_-1`;
```

But for two children, we need a lot more logic, since the second child must be younger (or the same age) as the first:

```
type TwoChildren<A extends string[] = AgeGroups, Previous extends string[] = []> =
    A extends [infer Head extends string, ...infer Tail extends string[]]
        ? `2_${Head}_${Exclude<Head | Previous[number], "-1">}` | TwoChildren<Tail, [...Previous, Head]>
        : never;
```

Since `AgeGroups` is a tuple, we can "iterate" over it. Every iteration we store all the previous elements we already iterated over. Then in the next iteration, we can use the previous elements in the result (still making sure to exclude "-1").

Three or more children should be handled the same as two children:

```
type ThreeOrMoreChildren = TwoChildren;
```

So when you're done you'll end up with

```
type ValidCombos = ZeroChildren | OneChild | TwoChildren | ThreeOrMoreChildren;
```

which can be simplified to

```
type ValidCombos = ZeroChildren | OneChild | TwoChildren;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WG2Vvm)